# Issue with array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

The issue I have is that I can't get the value I want from the array which I'm sending to jQuery

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
  let data = event.data
  if (data.action == "open") {
    $('body').fadeIn(500)
    $(".g").html('')  

    fetch(`https://${GetParentResourceName()}/odjeca`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
        })
    }).then(allMyOutfits => allMyOutfits.json()).then(function(allMyOutfits){
      allMyOutfits.forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item["pedComponents"]) // Prints object object object
        console.log(JSON.Stringify(item.pedComponents)) // Prints like I want
        $(".g").append(`
          <div class="mojaorg2" id="odabirOdjece" pedComponents = "${item.pedComponents}">
            <p>${item.name}</p>
          </div>
        `)
      })
    })
  }
})
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong, I'm new to jQuery so I don't know a lot.

Comment: `item.pedComponents` is an object, you need to access its properties. Can you show an example of the stringified output and explain what should be in the DIV?

Comment: Sorry If I messed up with the post , first time posting xd.
The output from item.pedComponents stringified is like this
https://i.imgur.com/jjREF4Y.png
In the div I just need {item.name} 
And I need to send the values from item.pedComponents to another document function

Comment: you can't put an object in an HTML attribute, you can only put text.

Comment: Also, IDs should be unique, you shouldn't use the same `id="odabirOdjece"` every time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an object in an object attribute, attributes are only strings.

You can use jQuery's `data` feature to associate arbitrary data with an element.

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  let data = event.data
  if (data.action == "open") {
    $('body').fadeIn(500)
    $(".g").html('')

    fetch(`https://${GetParentResourceName()}/odjeca`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({})
    }).then(allMyOutfits => allMyOutfits.json()).then(function(allMyOutfits) {
      allMyOutfits.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item["pedComponents"]) // Prints object object object
        console.log(JSON.Stringify(item.pedComponents)) // Prints like I want
        $(".g").append(
          $("<div>", {
            "class": "mojaorg2",
            data: {
              penComponents: item.pedComponents
            }
            html: $("p", {
              text: item.name
            })
          }));
      })
    })
  }
})
```

You can later retrieve the value with `$(element).data("pedComponents")`